# How to fix a while statement to display correct cout?

Tags: c++

How can I get the `cout` in the body of my `while` statement to print outside of it? The reason is because when I try writing the sentence accompanied in the line of `cout << password;` it would mess up my `password`.

For example, if I write `cout << "this is your new password " << password;`, it would display the sentence with a number at the end.

I would appreciate if someone could give me some help.

Below is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Introduction on how the password generator works
    cout << "This program will help you generate a passowrd."
        << "\nPlease enter your password in character or number followed by <ENTER> key."
        << "\n*Please note that character must be in lower case letters or digits.*" << endl
        << "Input your Password: ";

    //char to hold user password
    char password;
    //user input for password
    cin.get(password);
    //while loop for password until it hit a blank
    while (password !='\n')
    {
    //if and else if statement for password
        if (password == 'a' || password == 'b' || password == 'c' || password == '1')
        {
            password = '1';

        }

        else if (password == 'd' || password == 'e' || password == 'f' || password == '2')
        {
            password = '2';
        }

        else if (password == 'g' || password == 'h' || password == 'i' || password == '3')
        {
            password = '3';
        }

        else if (password == 'j' || password == 'k' || password == 'l' || password == '4')
        {
            password = '4';
        }

        else if (password == 'm' || password == 'n' || password == 'l' || password == '5')
        {
            password = '5';
        }

        else if (password == 'p' || password == 'q' || password == 'r' || password == '6')
        {
            password = '6';
        }

        else if (password == 's' || password == 't' || password == 'u' || password == '7')
        {
            password = '7';
        }

        else if (password == 'v' || password == 'w' || password == 'x' || password == '8')
        {
            password = '8';
        }

        else if (password == 'y' || password == 'z' || password == '9')
        {
            password = '9';
        }
        else
        {
            password = '?';
        }

        // cout to print new password
        cout <<password;
        //cin.get to restart loop
        cin.get(password);

    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for you, I think it is time to learn to use switch-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the `cout` inside the `while` loop to print afterwards. If its in the while-loop, it will be executed every loop (until surrounded by an if or so).

So you have two options:

1. Print your sentence before you enter the while-loop like this:

   ```
   cout << "Your new password...";
   while(password!='\n'){
       ...
       cout << password;
   }
   ```
2. Store your "passwords" (which are not really words but single chars) in a string like this:

   ```
   std::string str = "";
   while(password!='\n'){
       ...
       str += password;
   }
   cout << "Your new password..." << str;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "endl" to show your password in a new line, then it will not be messed up:

```
cout << "this is your new password " <<endl<< password;
```

Comment: You can also use `'\n'`. which is shorter and has less overhead. <g>